# SSRS 2005 vs ADFS vs IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7, reporting-services, windows-server-2008, wif, adfs

I have installed SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 on a Windows 2008 R2 machine and have successfully integrated Windows Authentication on the report server and report manager virtual applications. Do you know if it is possible to integrate the report manager and report server to ADFS?

I have found some really helpful [tutorials](http://blogs.technet.com/b/adfs/archive/2007/05/07/configuring-sql-reporting-services-to-use-adfs-authentication.aspx) but have so far not managed to find any information relating to running report virtual applications under IIS 7.5 with ADFS. Running under IIS 6 looks possible.

Comment: As far as I know, SSRS has no support for claims-based security. This may have changed in later versions or there may be third-party solutions. I'd be very interested to know of any, myself.

Comment: Support for claims authentication is available in SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012, added to support integration with SharePoint 2010. More details here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487970(v=sql.105).aspx